# No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type, VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, bitmap, picturebox

I have a problem saving images from PictureBox1 to my SQL server database, I've done my research and found out that I have to convert my image to a byte array in order to do that but I don't know how to apply it in this code that I'm trying to edit. When I click on the save button I get this error: `No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type`.

I think it has something to do with inserting the image to the database so I'll show you code snippets that are related to it.

This is the class with its properties:

```
Friend Class PersonFile
    Private _NewID As String

 Private _PersonID As String
    Friend Property PersonID() As String
        Get
            Return _PersonID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _PersonID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
 Private _Photo As Image
    Friend Property Photo() As Image
        Get
            Return _Photo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Image)
            _Photo = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is the function for insert:

```
Friend Class PersonFileDB
 Friend Function DXInsertFile(ByVal cItem As PersonFile) As PersonFile
        Dim cReturn As New PersonFile

 Using oleCON As New SqlConnection(AppVariables.GConnectionString)
            oleCON.Open()

 Dim n1 As String = ""
            n1 = CreateNewID()
            cItem.PersonID = n1

            Dim xSQL As New StringBuilder
            xSQL.AppendLine(" INSERT INTO PersonData ")
            xSQL.AppendLine("( ")
            xSQL.AppendLine(" PersonID, ")
            xSQL.AppendLine(" Photo, ")
            ''Other code...
            xSQL.AppendLine("VALUES ( ")
            xSQL.AppendLine(" @PersonID, ")
            xSQL.AppendLine(" @Photo, ")
            ''Other code...

            Dim oleComm As New SqlCommand(xSQL.ToString, oleCON)
            With oleComm.Parameters
                .AddWithValue(" @PersonID, ", cItem.PersonID)
                .AddWithValue("@Photo", cItem.Photo)
            ''Other code...
            End With

            Dim n As Integer
            n = oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If n <> 0 Then
                cItem.Updated = True
                SaveNewID(CInt(cItem.PersonID))
                cReturn = cItem
            End If
 End Using
 Return cReturn
End Function
```

This is the click event:

```
Private CurrPerson As New PersonFile

Private Sub cmdPersonSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPersonSave.Click

        CurrPerson.Photo = PictureBox1.Image
        ''Other code...
  Dim cdb As New PersonFileDB

        Select Case cmdPersonSave.Text
            Case "Add"
                UIClear()
                UISetControls(False)
                cmdPersonSave.Text = "Save"
                cmdPersonUpdate.Text = "Cancel"
                cmdPersonDelete.Enabled = False
                cmdSearch.Enabled = False
            Case "Save"
                If EditMode Then
                    CurrPerson = cdb.DXUpdateFile(CurrPerson)
                    EditMode = False
                Else
                    CurrPerson = cdb.DXInsertFile(CurrPerson)
                End If
                If CurrPerson.Updated Then
                    BindGrid(CurrPerson.PersonID)
                    UISetControls(True)
                End If
                cmdPersonSave.Text = "Add"
                cmdPersonUpdate.Text = "Edit"
                cmdPersonDelete.Enabled = True
                cmdSearch.Enabled = True
                UISetControls(True)
        End Select
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SERVER database have datatype **IMAGE**. Keep the column datatype as **IMAGE**.

You can use the following sample code and pass Image to the below function which converts the image to byte to store in database.

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.Close();

                byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }
```

Comment: How do you code it in VB.NET? Where should I put that code? Or how does it fit in my code? As you can see, I'm a newbie here. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You can convert this code to VB.NET. Lots of online code converters are available.

Comment: Where exactly should I put it in my code as indicated in my question above?

Comment: @PareshJ, `Image` data types are depricated and should not be used. It is recommended to use `VarBinary(max)` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: @Irond64dpool, if you use his example, you would use it here: `.AddWithValue("@Photo", ImageToByte2(cItem.Photo))`

Comment: @PareshJ, Good thing you pointed that out, I didn't know `Image` data types won't be used in future versions of SQL server, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm getting an error - SqlException was unhandled
`Incorrect syntax near '@PersonID'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@PersonID".`

Comment: Your code has `.AddWithValue(" @PersonID, ", cItem.PersonID)`  There's a space before @ and a comma,space after... neither of those should be there.
`.AddWithValue("@PersonID", cItem.PersonID)` should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define an image path named "imgpath"

```
//upload image

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();

    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg; *.png; *.gif)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif";
    if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        imgpath.Text = opf.FileName;
        pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
    }
}
// ADD NEW/INSERT IMAGE TO DB
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = imgpath.Text;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(imgpath.Text);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgpath.Text, FileMode.Open, 
     FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

    if (imgpath.Text != "")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_Record(@StudentImage)", con);
        con.Open();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

       // must use toolbox to add picturebox
        pictureBox3.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox3.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentImage", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = 
       bytes;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Succeed");
        DisplayData();
        ClearData();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill Required Informations!");
    }
}
```